# Go does not detect `sync` package

Tags: go

I get `error: reference to undefined identifier ‘sync.Pool’` message and this is working in Playground. What should I do?

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "sync"
)

func main() {
  var wg sync.Pool
  fmt.Println(wg)
}
```

Comment: please don't call your Pool wg, when there is a WaitGroup which is often referred to as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [installed go from source](http://golang.org/doc/install/source), check what `$GOROOT` et ^`$GOROOT_FINAL` refer to: if they differ, you need to reset your `GOROOT` to `GOROOT_FINAL`.

> The value assumed by installed binaries and scripts when `$GOROOT` is not set explicitly.
>   It defaults to the value of `$GOROOT`.
>
> If you want to build the Go tree in one location but move it elsewhere after the build, set `$GOROOT_FINAL` to the eventual location.

---

From the comments, the OP mentions:

> `go version` prints out

```
go version xgcc (Ubuntu 4.9.1-0ubuntu1) 4.9.1 linux/amd64
```

And `$GOROOT/pkg/linux_amd64/sync.a` does exist.

I recommended to make sure `$PATH` includes `$GOROOT/bin`
[JimB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32880/jimb) added:

> to be more specific, make sure your `$PATH` contains `$GOROOT/bin` for the correct `GOROOT`. I think you have two installations making this more confusing.

Comment: I did. And go version prints out `go version xgcc (Ubuntu 4.9.1-0ubuntu1) 4.9.1 linux/amd64`

Comment: @MaynardRobert then what do you see in your `$GOROOT/pkg/<your_arch>/` folder? Do you see a `sync.a` file?

Comment: Yes I do see `sync.a`

Comment: And my `go env` : GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/ubuntu/go/bin"
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/ubuntu/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
TERM="dumb"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-g -O2 -fPIC -m64 -pthread"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"

Comment: Then how do I set up the correct path? `GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"`

Comment: @MaynardRobert make sure `$PATH` includes `$GOROOT/bin`

Comment: @MaynardRobert: to be more specific, make sure your `$PATH` contains `$GOROOT/bin` for the correct GOROOT. I think you have two installations making this more confusing.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have the correct version of Go installed. `sync.Pool` was only added in Go 1.3. Try updating your local go package, verify you are running 1.3, and try again.

Comment: I do. I installed from source. And has go1.3

Comment: What does `go version` say?